# Class cast exception occurring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am getting a ClassCastException, and I don't know why. This is my code:

```
public class RestLocationService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getAllRestDetails();
    }

    public static List<RestLocation> getAllRestDetails() {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<RestLocation> restDetails = new ArrayList<RestLocation>();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            Query query = session.createQuery(" from RestLocation ");

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Object[]> list = query.list();

            for (Object[] arr : list) {
                System.out.print(Integer.parseInt((String) arr[0]));
                System.out.println("\t" + arr[1].toString());
                System.out.println("\t" + arr[2].toString());
                System.out.println("\t" + arr[3].toString());
                System.out.println("\t" + arr[4].toString());
                System.out.println("\t" + arr[5].toString());
                System.out.println("\t" + arr[6].toString());
                System.out.println("\t" + arr[7].toString());
                System.out.println("\t" + arr[8].toString());
                System.out.println("\t" + arr[9].toString());
                System.out.println("\t" + arr[10].toString());
                System.out.println("\t" + arr[11].toString());
                System.out.println("\t" + arr[12].toString());

                RestLocation details = new RestLocation();
                details.setRestId(Integer.parseInt((String) arr[0]));
                details.setGeoX(arr[1].toString());
                details.setGeoY(arr[2].toString());
                details.setAddress1(arr[3].toString());
                details.setAddress2(arr[4].toString());
                details.setAddress3(arr[5].toString());
                details.setArea(arr[6].toString());
                details.setTown(arr[7].toString());
                details.setPostcode(arr[8].toString());
                details.setState(arr[9].toString());
                details.setCountry(arr[10].toString());
                details.setLandmark(arr[11].toString());
                details.setSmartCode(arr[12].toString());
                restDetails.add(details);
            }
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
        return restDetails;
    }
}
```

I am getting the error like this:

> ```
> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
> log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
> log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
> Hibernate Configuration loaded
> Hibernate serviceRegistry created
> Hibernate: select restlocati0_.REST_ID as REST_ID1_0_, restlocati0_.ADDRESS_LINE1 as ADDRESS_2_0_, restlocati0_.ADDRESS_LINE2 as ADDRESS_3_0_, restlocati0_.ADDRESS_LINE3 as ADDRESS_4_0_, restlocati0_.AREA as AREA5_0_, restlocati0_.COUNTRY as COUNTRY6_0_, restlocati0_.GEO_X as GEO_X7_0_, restlocati0_.GEO_Y as GEO_Y8_0_, restlocati0_.LANDMARK as LANDMARK9_0_, restlocati0_.POSTCODE as POSTCOD10_0_, restlocati0_.ZIPPR_SMART_CODE as ZIPPR_S11_0_, restlocati0_.STATE as STATE12_0_, restlocati0_.TOWN as TOWN13_0_ from fhv1.restlocation restlocati0_
> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hitsquad.model.RestLocation cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
>     at com.hitsquad.service.RestLocationService.getAllRestDetails(RestLocationService.java:36)
>     at com.hitsquad.service.RestLocationService.main(RestLocationService.java:18)
> ```

Comment: What do you not understand about the Stacktrace? What's the [mcve] that you can create which will reproduce the problem? Have you tried debugging the code to see what's happening when the error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query returns a list of RestLocation objects. You are assigning the results to a List of Object[] objects. When you try to iterate the list each element is cast to an Object[] Hence a ClassCastException.

Change your code to

```
 List<RestLocation> list = query.list();

 for (RestLocation location: list) {
            //access RestLocation properties
 }
```

Comment: thanks ekem chitsiga